# Build single test in go

Tags: unit-testing, go, delve

I have two tests in my project, I would like to build a single test, place the resulting binary in a container, run it, and then attach a debugger.

Is this possible?

```
package dataplatform

import "testing"

func TestA(t *testing.T) {

    // test A
}

func TestRunCommand(t *testing.T) {

    // Test B
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may use `-run <regexp>` to limit (filter) the tests to run. So for example if you want to run only the `TestA()` test, you may do it like this:

```
go test -run TestA
```

Actually the above will run all tests whose names contain `TestA`, so to be explicit, it would be:

```
go test -run ^TestA$
```

To not run the tests but generate the test binary, you may use the `-c` option:

```
go test -c
```

This won't run the tests, but compile a binary which when executed will run the tests.

The problem is that you can't combine these options, e.g. running

```
go test -c -run TestA
```

Will generate a binary which when executed will run all tests.

The truth is that the generated binary accepts the same parameters as `go test`, so you may pass `-run TestA` to the generated binary, but you must prefix the params with `test`:

> Each of these flags is also recognized with an optional 'test.' prefix, as in -test.v. When invoking the generated test binary (the result of 'go test -c') directly, however, the prefix is mandatory.

So if the name of the generated test binary is `my.test`, run it like:

```
./my.test -test.run TestA
```

For more options and documentation, run `go help test`, or visit the official documentation:

[Command Go](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)

And the relevant section:

[Command Go: Testing flags](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags)